# Finding an array element by id returned by Active Record collection in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to synchronize members in the db with an external source

My plan was to use the array collection in the active record class and on each update for a member found in the external source, I would remove that member entry in the array(if it exists) then after I am done iterating the external source I would iterate and operate on the members left in the array.

The question is how to find the index for the array with a specified id?

```
member_queue    Array[2]    
[0] #<Member:0x7181404> 
    @attributes Hash[9] 
        'name'  "Steve" 
        'id'    "953125641"     
    @attributes_cache   Hash[0] 
[1] #<Member:0x717fb68> 
    @attributes Hash[9] 
    @attributes_cache   Hash[0]
```

for example, I would search for id="953125641" and that would return 0 so I could delete that entry from the array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd look at using the [index](http://www.rubybrain.com/api/ruby-1.8.7/doc/index.html?a=M002081&name=find_index) function. It's similar to C++'s find_if function (if that's any help!)

```
index = member_queue.index {|m| m == "953125641" }
```

Comment: I am getting this error:
    irb(main):001:0> [1,2,3].index {|x|x==2}
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
        from (irb):1:in `index'
        from (irb):1

Comment: 1.8.6 - I am using aptana studio, I guess I'll try to figure out how to updage

Comment: I updated to 1.9.1 using http://blog.orangecabin.com/2009/05/install-ruby-1-9-on-windows-using-zip-binary/ and it works!